# Web Deploy with multiple azure instances

Tags: windows, deployment, azure

I wanted to know if it is possible to use Azure's Web Deploy feature when you have a Web Role with more than one instance.  I received a warning message that indicated that I couldn't do this but my common sense tells me that there is probably an easier way to update my deployed project as the Web Deploy feature did than having to go through the hour long process of publishing the Azure project to update a few files.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.  You need to do full deploys.  Web deploys are better suited for 1-instance roles that are in QA/DEV/debugging mode